# for what My mysql server get mr than 2 gig RAM on my vps?

Tags: mysql, centos

imnot know english very well so sory for my bad dictation

on my vps that has 4 gigabyte RAM and 4 core CPU and 220 gig HDD .
i haved installed centos basic server 6.5 x64 and virtualmin last version upto today .
but after installing and setup a  BIND Server and a simple virtual host over Nginx web server

i saw that have 12 proccess that allocated 840 MB of my RAM 
thats proccess named in htop : mysqld

for what ?

and how to solve this problem ?

[image: screen shot of htop]
[image: screen shot of virtualmin panel]

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing on htop are not processes, but "light processes" or more commonly named "[threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))". MySQL will only use one process for its server (plus one for its wrapper/watchdog mysqld_safe. You can check that by executing `pstree`, which will show clearly differentiated the child threads with curly braces, for example:

```
init─┬─agetty
     ├─atd
     ├─auditd───{auditd}
     ├─crond
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─dhclient
     ├─httpd───8*[httpd]
     ├─6*[mingetty]
     ├─mysqld_safe───mysqld───33*[{mysqld}]
     ├─nagios───{nagios}
     ├─ntpd
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─2*[sendmail]
     ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
     └─udevd───udevd
```

MySQL is a "single process" executable, but it is multithreaded, which means that it will use a separate thread for each SQL connection, plus some additional ones for so called "background processes". This is a good thing because if the server is idle, it will not take extra memory (memory is shared with all the other threads), but if the server is busy, it can parallelize tasks like IO writes, read-aheads, unnecessary-data purges and secondary index changes (for example, for InnoDB). Again, that is a good thing and not a problem. All the threads together are using 840MB, not each of them. That is something that htop may not be very clear about.

If you didn't installed manually MySQL, you should investigate which of your services installed requires it and what it is being used for.

If 840MB is too much for mysqld on your 2GB ram server, as it may not be a dedicated server, I can tell you ways to minimize memory usage my changing its configuration:

- Disable the performance-schema metrics
- Disable your query cache
- Reduce your buffer pool size (defaults to 128 MB)
- Reduce per-connection usage by setting per-conection buffers lower (sort-buffer-size, join-buffer-size, etc.) and reducing the number of concurrent connections (max-connections)

Obviously, some of these will reduce your performance and/or drop functionality. Some of them require a server restart.

Please also note that memory usage being maximised is usually a good thing, as memory not used directly by applications tends to be used for filesystem cache, making disk access faster. Unless you do not have swapping activity (or predict to have it), memory usage is a good thing.